# Check if remoteMessage.getData().get("Pic") != null

Tags: java, android, firebase

I'm using Firebase cloud messaging and one of the parameters is optional. I have following method below

```
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
        String picUrl = null;

        String toTel = remoteMessage.getData().get("To").toString();
        if (remoteMessage.getData().get("Pic") != null)
            picUrl = remoteMessage.getData().get("Pic").toString();
}
```

However I'm getting an exception at the if statement line

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.toString()' on a null object reference
```

How can I successfully check to is there is a value for "Pic"?

Comment: maybe the problem is `remoteMessage.getData().get("To").toString()`, or maybe it should only be called once

Comment: no, it works fine without the if statement, and the exception does show the line number of the if statement

Comment: *works fine without the if statement* - please edit your question to show what you mean

Comment: *works fine wihtout the if statement* - post the stack trace and tell us which line threw the exception.

Comment: I do not believe this code throws this exception. I suspect the real code was `if (remoteMessage.getData().get("Pic").toString() != null)`. Note the `.toString()` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tend to use `containsKey` method rather than checking for null, maybe try this

```
if (remoteMessage.getData().containsKey("Pic")) {
    picUrl = data.get("Pic");
}
```